# Styleguidist - Build with dev webpack config

Tags: webpack, react-styleguidist

`styleguidist server` works perfectly (thanks very much)

I would now like to build the static html files for sticking in github pages but..

`styleguidist build` throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined` which seems to originate from favicons-webpack-plugin which is only used in my production webpack config.

It seems that `styleguidist build` passes the `-p` flag to webpack (or otherwise causes this config to be used) but I would prefer to just build with the dev config.

Anyone know how or if this is possible?

Comment: seems to be a bug, better report that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still having this issue, but I just ran into it setting up a new Styleguidist project with Create React App and Typescript....had the same issue, dev server worked fine, but something in the production build settings of create-react-app was causing conflicts with styleguidist's own internal things.

In styleguide.config.js, appended in my set up object

```
module.exports = {
  // ...other configgy stuff,
    webpackConfig: require('./node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js')(
    'development'
  ),
};
```

Not sure if this is 100% right but works for my situation.
Based on styleguidist's docs, some of the stuff set up for create-react-app may break the process

https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/webpack.html#reusing-your-projects-webpack-config

I guess you can also just do this..I just found it after hacking this fix
https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/cookbook#how-to-use-production-or-development-build-of-react

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development react-styleguidist build"
  }
}
```

haven't tried that yet...guess I should have RTFM'ed first